# Why are tables not appearing in-text in APA7 even after using floatsintext?

Tags: apa-style, apa7

I am using the `man` option in documentclass `apa7`.

The tables and images in the manuscript appear at the end of the article. I was able to get the images to appear in-text with

`\documentclass[man,floatsintext]{apa7}`

But this is not making the tables appear in-text, despite what I read from the documentation for the `apa7` class.

What can I do to make the tables appear in-text?

Comment: Always show a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). Since you don't show any code, it's impossible to know whether something in your code interfers with the option.

Comment: Is maybe one of the `table` Floats, and one of the `figure` floats, quite large? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico That indeed seems to be the case! I was able to reduce the text size of one table and get it to appear in-text. The rest are not budging. What can I try?

Comment: @Eli --Assuming  you initiate floats with `\begin{figure}[htbp]` and `\begin{table}[htbp]`, be sure to add an `!` (exclamation mark) character, i.e., do  write `\begin{figure}[htbp!]` and `\begin{table}[htbp!]`. The purpose of the `!` specifier is to override possibly restrictive settings the document class may be imposing on where LaTeX is alloed to place floats.

Comment: @Mico I was able to solve the issue by changing `\begin{table*}` to `\begin{table}` for my particular case. But it was indeed your pointing out the possible size issue that helped me figure it out. If you write an answer, I'll be happy to accept it. Thanks!!

Comment: @Ell - I'm glad my suggestion turned out to be useful. Given that my suggestion was actually no more than a hunch, I wouldn't want to post it as a full answer unless you're willing to edit your query to provide some more pertinent information about the nature of the floats in your document, such as that several are quite large.